# Flutter - How do I know that user came from DeepLink

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking

I have a mobile application that can be opened by an xcrun command from the console, simulating the deeplink. My problem is that I can't identify where the user came from. Is there any flag/Boolean variable that I can reach that the User opened the app via this link?

I have a generateRoute method where different route names return different PageRoutes. My app redirects to the page I want to show to deeplink users but I want to get them to splash screen first, then to the desired page? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are You Using [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)?

Comment: No, I'm not using any plugin.

Comment: I think [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) will be very good for you. and this is a little useful [tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/deep-linking-in-flutter-with-firebase-dynamic-links-8a4b1981e1eb) for you

Answer (score 1):

One way is to always pass an argument when navigating within the application and assume `deepLink` when the argument is not present. Something like this:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
  '/your/path',
  arguments: <String, bool>{
    'deepLink': false,
  },
);
```

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, bool>;
final deepLink = args.containsKey('deepLink') ? args['deepLink']! : true;
```